# What's the proper way to modify a string in a worker thread then read the result in the main thread?

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I was passing a an empty string from the main thread to a worker thread, then having the worker thread modify the string, and at a later time the main thread needed to be able to read the string.  Of course, the string was being passed by value not by reference, so it couldn't be modified.  I was able to get around this by passing a string array of size 1, but I would like to know if there's a cleaner way to solve this issue.

```
//in main thread
    string errorMessage="";
    System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => { 
        ProcessImport(path, errorMessage); });
    thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();

//in worker thread
    if(errorDetected)
    {
        errorMesage= "some message";
    }

//later in main thread
    if(errorMessage!="")
    {
         CreateFeedbackMessageBox(erorrMesssage, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you set the apartment state to STA?

Comment: Don't use `Thread` at all.  If you want to run some background work in another thread use `Task.Run`.  You can `await` the returned task to get it's result or to catch any exceptions it throws in the event that it errors.  The code you have is completely unsafe and can break in any number of different ways because you're not synchronizing shared state between threads.

Comment: Could ProcessImport have errorMessage as out parameter ? It's a little dirty but it answer the question.

Comment: @KiwiJaune No, it couldn't.

Comment: @Fildor, I didn't write that part of the code, I'm not sure why it's setting the apartment state.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, that seems like a much cleaner way to do it.